# How to print in InDesign several small sized pages on one sheet

Tags: printing, thumbnails, adobe-indesign

Here is what I'm trying to do: 
I have four single pages in InDesign. Each of them is 150x100mm small. Now I want to print them out, but it would be perfect to have all them on one sheet of paper. After hitting cmd+P there is the thumbnails option in InDesign – but this one changes the original sizes. I would like to keep the original size and print several pages on a single sheet of paper. How to do that? Is there a script for that?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best regards,
Serkan

Comment: The question is too general, you have to show what you tried or clearly state a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

To arrange pages side by side and print them as a spread is not a solution?

Comment: This is not a solution for a fast working process. If I need only one print – yes then I can arrange them side by side; but if I have to print every 5 minutes new design solutions then I need a much faster way.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more convoluted than it needs to be but perhaps you could  1) export the designs to a PDF, then 2) import the PDF back to a new InDesign file, each page in a text box, keeping them at 150 x 100 mm, then 3) print the pages of the output document.

If you always save the PDF in the same location and with the same name, the placed PDF should automatically update (as any modified link can). You can save importing a placing each of the four pages every time that way.

This can probably also be scripted if you want to go even faster.